# communication between two phone via USB

Tags: usb, communication

I want to communication between two different android phone via USB. I look at Google SDK guide I don't know how can i do.Somebody can give me some suggests ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Does one of the phones support USB OTG? Unless one of the devices supports OTG or you use a special device in the middle, the phones can't talk to each other over USB because neither of them can act as a host.

Comment: yes one of the phone support USB OTG.

Answer (score 0):

The USB-Standard requires to work as host-client-mechanism. This means in particular, that you usually have a host-controller (for example inside your PC) which a client (USB-drive, MP3-player, mobile phone) can connect to.
The host is responsible for negotiating and establishing a connection. If you want to connect two clients with each other, one of them must Support USB-On-The-Go to serve as a host with limited capabilities.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus)

> The design architecture of USB is asymmetrical in its topology, consisting of a host, a multitude of downstream USB ports, and multiple peripheral devices connected in a tiered-star topology. Additional USB hubs may be included in the tiers, allowing branching into a tree structure with up to five tier levels. A USB host may implement multiple host controllers and each host controller may provide one or more USB ports. Up to 127 devices, including hub devices if present, may be connected to a single host controller.[20][21] USB devices are linked in series through hubs. One hub—built into the host controller—is the root hub.